# [ROS2] Do these package.xml and CMakeLists.txt tags have alternatives in ament and colcon builds for ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to port a package.xml and CMakeLists files from ros1 to ros2. I have this tag in the original XML file

`<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>`

Is there an alternative for this in ros2 with rclcpp and ament?

Also, the CMakeLists.txt file has

`SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(src/file.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)`

`add_dependencies(<target> ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})`

I wanted to know if there are any alternatives in ROS2

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357479/%5Bros2%5D-do-these-package.xml-and-cmakelists.txt-tags-have-alternatives-in-ament-and-colcon-builds-for-ros2?/) by [Jaroan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50126/jaroan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have this tag in the original XML file
>
> `<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>`
>
> Is there an alternative for this in ros2 with rclcpp and ament?

This is in the `package.xml` and a tag of the format 2 version. According to the [migration guide](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/Migration-Guide/#id1) ROS2 support `package.xml`s of the format 2 and higher versions. So you should be good to go.

`SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES` and `add_dependencies` are actually `cmake` functions and thus, there is no ROS2 alternative.

However, you can use `ament_target_dependencies` instead of the `add_dependencies` call, which is an easier way to handle that.

I suggest you thoroughly work through the migration guide linked above.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaroan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50126/jaroan/) on 2020-07-21**:
Thank you, I was referring to that site, but I didn't find some specific instructions. I'll go through them again